# Tablesorter VS PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, tablesorter, pagedlist

I'm working on a project where I have to fetch data from a database then present results in tables with at least 200 rows until 3000 rows.

I tried first Pagedlist and noticed that only the fixed number of records per page is displayed in the client side and each time when the user change the page, there is a new request to the server.

For tablesorter, I noticed that all the results are displayed and paging is only visual (only the presentation of table) but everything is in the client side

Is my understanding correct?

What I want to know is which approach is better (in time execution)?

Actually I'm working on localhost and there is only me as user so I can't notice the difference even tablesorter take more time to load in the first time but after it's very quick meanwhile the pagedlist method is faster in loading page but each time it request the server to change page and load the according data

When finished the application will be in the server and many users will have access to the application to add, search delete...

Which of these two approaches is a better choice?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this DataTables demo](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html) with infinite scroll? It dynamically loads in rows as the user scrolls.

Comment: @Mottie I think you are the owner of http://mottie.github.com, is there a way to combine tablesorter with this DataTables, and when you say dynamically loads;it means it will request the server to load the rest rows?

Comment: If it's the case that you are the owner, is there a way to show|hide columns with tablesorter? thanks

Comment: Yes, I am the same person. I haven't tried, but I doubt DataTables & tablesorter are compatible together. And, I do think DataTables handles server interaction better. Right now, there isn't anything in place to hide/show columns in tablesorter (I am planning to make a widget soon); but honestly if you have 3000 rows, it's going to be very very slow if all of them are in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Mottie ok will try tablesorter and dataTables together, and I'm waiting for the widgets :)